# How do I remove transparency from a histogram created using Seaborn in python?

Tags: python, colors, histogram, seaborn

I'm creating histograms using seaborn in python and want to customize the colors. The default settings create transparent histograms, and I would like mine to be solid. How do I remove the transparency?

I've tried creating a color palette and setting desaturation to 0, but this hasn't changed the saturation of the resulting histogram.

Example:

```
# In[1]:

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')


# In[2]:

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")


# In[3]:

myColors = ['#115e67','#f4633a','#ffd757','#4da2e8','#cfe5e5']
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette(myColors))


# In[4]:

sns.set_palette(palette=myColors,desat=0)


# In[5]:

sns.set(style="white")


# In[6]:

sns.despine()


# In[7]:

plt.title('Distribution of Petal Length')
sns.distplot(iris.petal_length, axlabel = 'Petal Length')
```

[Distribution of petal length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5j7P.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
sns.distplot(iris.petal_length, axlabel = 'Petal Length', hist_kws=dict(alpha=1))
```