# Colors in seaborn vary depending on type of graph?

Tags: python, seaborn, color-palette

I had the need to define a pallete in seaborn, as shown below:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEB8u.png)

This worked fine, as the color was good when called:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYhHo.png)

However, when calling the same color using a different type of plot, the result is rather different: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVUN8.png)

What's happening here? Is seaborn applying some kind of hue depending on the plot type?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Seaborn barplot desaturating colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272875/why-is-seaborn-barplot-desaturating-colors)

Comment: Please carefully read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: See [How do I remove transparency from a histogram created using Seaborn in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078810/how-do-i-remove-transparency-from-a-histogram-created-using-seaborn-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the histogram bars drawn by `sns.histplot` are drawn partly transparently, causing the colours to be lighter. According to [the `distplot` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html), you can override the opacity of the histogram by providing an `alpha` keyword via the `hist_kws` argument:

```
sns.distplot(…, hist_kws={'alpha': 1})
```

Note that, if you are just drawing a histogram and not using the kernel density estimate or rug features from seaborn, you might just as well directly call [`ax.hist` from matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html), e.g.:

```
ax[0].plot(total_nofda["eccentricConnectivityIndexDescriptor"], bins=100, color=c('blue'))
```

Edit to add: Indeed, seaborn's `distplot` automatically sets the alpha (opacity value) of the histogram to `0.4`. From [`seaborn`'s GitHub:](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/distributions.py#L2602)

```
if hist:
    # …
    hist_kws.setdefault("alpha", 0.4)
    # …
```

Comment: Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.